# Breeze adding a child entity to a parent entity fails on save

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I am using angular for the front end with breeze for connecting to an EF model.  I have a parent entity (ProjectTeam) and it contains a property which is an array of child elements (ProjectTeamAssociates).  I am also using an xeditable grid for the editing of two arrays.

If I add a new team and save, breeze will save it correctly to the DB.

```
// add teamuser
function addTeam() {
    vm.inserted = datacontext.createEntity("ProjectTeam");  //create new entity
    vm.inserted.ProjectID = currentID.id;  //set current project id
    vm.contributingTeams.push(vm.inserted);  //add the new team to all teams
};
```

If I add a new associate to an existing team and save it will also work.

```
// add associate
function addAssociate() {
    vm.assocInserted = datacontext.createEntity("ProjectTeamAssociate");
    vm.assocInserted.ProjectID = currentID.id;
    vm.assocInserted.ProjectTeamID = vm.selectedTeam.ProjectTeamID;
    vm.selectedTeam.ProjectTeamAssociates.push(vm.assocInserted);
    //vm.contributingAssociates.push(vm.assocInserted);
};
```

Other code of importance:

```
function setAssociates(team) {  
//when i select a team; team is from an ng-repeat on vm.contributingTeams
    vm.selectedTeam = team;
    vm.contributingAssociates = team.ProjectTeamAssociates;
}
```

When I try to add a new team and then add a new associate to the team I will get an error:  "An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Breeze.ContextProvider.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ContributingTeamAssociate_ContributingTeam". The conflict occurred in database "Optimus", table "dbo.ContributingTeam", column 'ContributingTeamID'.

The statement has been terminated."

I've been looking at the breeze docs, SO, any random website for advice and I can't seem to figure out why breeze won't add both at once.  My data is:

```
entities
    [Object { ProjectTeamAssociateID=-2,  ProjectTeamID=-1,  AssociateID="00012333",  more...}, Object { ProjectTeamID=-1,  ProjectID=55555,  TeamID=77,  more...}]

[0]
    Object { ProjectTeamAssociateID=-2,  ProjectTeamID=-1,  AssociateID="00012333",  more...}

AssociateID
    "00012333"

Note
    ""

ProjectTeamAssociateID
    -2

ProjectTeamID
    -1

StatusID
    10

TeamRoleID
    2

entityAspect
    Object { entityTypeName="ProjectTeamAssociate:#OptimusOnlineDataAccess",  defaultResourceName="ProjectTeamAssociates",  entityState="Added",  more...}

[1]
    Object { ProjectTeamID=-1,  ProjectID=55555,  TeamID=77,  more...}

Priority
    0

ProjectID
    55555

ProjectTeamID
    -1

StatusID
    6

TeamID
    77

entityAspect
    Object { entityTypeName="ProjectTeam:#OptimusOnlineDataAccess",  defaultResourceName="ProjectTeams",  entityState="Added",  more...}

saveOptions
    Object {}
```

Another note:  In the entity frame work we renamed Contributing to Project.

Any thoughts or pointers would be greatly appreciated.